# Retaining a value when switching back and forth between views 

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've set up two views:  ViewControllerOne and ViewControllerTwo.
In my ViewControllerTwo, I have a numeric variable (dataValue) that I input in a text field that I later use as a float value in a calculation.

The user can move to another Class view (ViewControllerOne), but when they return to ViewControllerTwo, the variable they inputted in the text field is not retained and returns to the default value I define in my ViewControllerTwo.m file.

How can I get my ViewControllerTwo to remember my dataValue?

I've @synthesized my dataValueTextField and defined my default dataValue in ViewControllerTwo.m:

```
@synthesize dataValueTextField;
float dataValue = 1.00;
```

Then, later, I've converted my dataValueTextField into a float value:

```
float textFieldData = [dataValueTextField.text floatValue];
dataValue = textFieldData;
```

But it never remembers dataValue when I switch views back and forth.  Do I need to add something to my viewWillDisappear or do I need to add something to my viewWillDisappear or ViewWillAppear methods?
Any help would be appreciated.  I've been grasping at straws trying different things to no avail.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that when you're switching views, its actually creating a new instance of the view controller each time?  That might explain the value resetting back to its default.  Another possibility is that you have code setting it to the default value being called from an event callback which is triggered whenever the view shows up.  You could try logging out all the event handlers and see whats getting called when switching between views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think that's the case (I'm not sure I even know how to create a new instance of the view controller), but I will check my code again.  I appreciate your response very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a memory warning, the View may be getting unloaded and then reloaded when you return to it causing viewDidLoad to be called again.  This would cause your value in the UITextField to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

dataValue is a float, which means it is a primitive. primitives are not retained and are lost at the end of each method. it looks by how you declare dataValue, it is a singleton? i'm not 100% on how singleton's are handled when you switch view, if they are released or are retained.

maybe best to make dataValue into a instance variable? like you did with dataValueTextField.

Comment: i will try this.  Hoping it works, I'm at my wits end. THANKS